# Display UIAlertController as long a function lasts

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a update function that is called when the refresh button in my app is pressed. 
In the update function I call some other functions that fetch the new data and then set all textfields with the new values. As long as the function is not completely performed, I would like to display an UIAlertController that shows the user an Alert Popup.
The code for the UIAlertController looks like this:

```
@IBAction func btnReloadDataTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refreshing Data", message: "This might take a few moments.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

     present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is there a clean way to perform this task with Swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all your tasks are finish, in your UIVIewController just call

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've approached a similar scenario using the `NotificationCenter` class. You could also approach this with a callback or delegate.

I will only discuss the NotificationCenter and callback approaches below as I do not think the delegate pattern is a good fit here.

**Here is what the Notification approach may look like:**

1. In the class/struct that is responsible for fetching the new data, you want create a notification using the NotificationCenter's `post` method.

Something like:

```
func fetchData() {
    // Code that fetches the new data...

    // Create the notification 
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "NewDataReceived", object: self)
}
```

2. Then in the `UIViewController` that has your reload button you want to add an observer when your controller is initiated.

Something like:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Create the observer
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, #selector(dismissAlertView), name: "NewDataReceived", object: nil)
}
```

3. When the notification is posted by your fetch data action, then your `UIViewController` will be notified and the method that you indicated in your observer will be called.
4. It is in this method that you can then dismiss the `UIAlertController`.

Something like:

```
// Also in your UIViewController...
func dismissAlertView() {
    refreshAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This will require that your UIAlertController be an instance property of your UIViewController.

The above code is just to illustrate the way you could approach this. I would recommend referring to the documentation for NotificationCenter.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter

**Here is what the callback approach may look like:**

1. Change the signature of the method responsible for fetching the data to take a function.

Something like:

```
func fetchData(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    // Code that fetches the new data...

    // Call the completion handler
    completionHandler()
}
```

2. Handle the callback in your UIViewController

Something like:

```
@IBAction func btnReloadDataTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refreshing Data", message: "This might take a few moments.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

     present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

     // Fetch your new data...
     someInstance.fetchData() {

         // Handle the callback of the fetch data call
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             refreshAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
     }
}
```

Again, this is just for illustration purposes. You can learn more about callbacks here: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/02/15/fundamentals-of-callbacks-for-swift-developers/